# Font error in Japan's version

Tags: java, cmd, fonts

Hi guys I'm now studying at Japan and here's my problem:

1. My code:

   ```
   class String4{
       public static void main(String[] args){
           String s="Hello.";
           char c = s.charAt(1);
           System.out.println(s +"の２文字目" + c + "です。");

           String s2 = s.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println(s +"を小文字にすると" + s2 + "です。");

           String s3 = s.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println(s +"を小文字にすると" + s3 + "です。");

           System.out.println("s2とHello.は等しい：" + s2.equals("Hello."));
           System.out.println("s2とHello.は等しい：" + s2.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello."));
       }
   }
   ```
2. My problem when runs on CMD:

   ```
   C:\Java>javac String4.java
   String4.java:5: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println(s +"é╠éQò╢ÄÜû┌" + c + "é┼é╖?B");
                                                 ^
   String4.java:8: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println(s +"é≡?¼ò╢ÄÜé╔é╖éΘé╞" + s2 + "é┼é╖?B");
                            ^
   String4.java:8: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println(s +"é≡?¼ò╢ÄÜé╔é╖éΘé╞" + s2 + "é┼é╖?B");
                                                        ^
   String4.java:11: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println(s +"é≡?¼ò╢ÄÜé╔é╖éΘé╞" + s3 + "é┼é╖?B");
                            ^
   String4.java:11: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println(s +"é≡?¼ò╢ÄÜé╔é╖éΘé╞" + s3 + "é┼é╖?B");
                                                        ^
   String4.java:13: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println("s2é╞Hello.é═ôÖé╡éó?F" + s2.equals("Hello."));
                                         ^
   String4.java:14: ???: ??????????????Cp1252?????????
   System.out.println("s2é╞Hello.é═ôÖé╡éó?F" + s2.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello."));
                                         ^
   ```

Comment: what is javascript doing here?

Comment: What is the output of the `CHCP` command?

Comment: CHCP command? what does it mean?
p.s: i'm newbie

Comment: @lit myc chcp code is 437

Comment: @BônLôiHổ - Codepage 437 is an English and Western European codepage which does not have any Japanese characters. Are you on Japanese Windows? What editor are you using to create the Java source code files? What happens if you use the command `CHCP 932`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the source file is in UTF-8:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8
```

Comment: or use UTF-8 Text file encoding

Comment: That works if the file is UTF-8 encoded. Is your file in codepage 932?

Comment: I don't know it well. Can you guide me a little bit detail? I'm a newbie